# Woocommerce get stock quantity of each item variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a page like this:

[image]

I have manage stocks enabled in variations, and I want to filter out items that are not in stock. For example, if size 9.5 is not available in variations, it should not appear in the front end as well. The questions posted here are all quite old and I could not get any of the suggestions posted in them to work. Here is what I have done so far:

```
// Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered
if ( taxonomy_exists( $attribute_name ) ) {

  $is_attr_color = false;
  $attribute_color = wc_sanitize_taxonomy_name( 'color' );
  if( $attribute_name == wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $attribute_color ) ){
    $is_attr_color = true;
  }
  $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $post->ID, $attribute_name, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );

  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, $options ) ) {
      continue;
    }
    if( $is_attr_color ){
      $datas = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'ts_product_color_config', true );
      if( strlen( $datas ) > 0 ){
        $datas = unserialize( $datas );
      }else{
        $datas = array(
              'ts_color_color'              => "#ffffff"
              ,'ts_color_image'                 => 0
            );

      }
    }

    $class = sanitize_title( $selected_value ) == sanitize_title( $term->slug ) ? 'selected' : '';
    $class .= ' option';
    if( $is_attr_color ){
      $class .= ' color';
    }

    echo '<div data-value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" class="' . $class . '">';

    if( $is_attr_color ){
      if( absint($datas['ts_color_image']) > 0 ){
        echo '<a href="#">' . wp_get_attachment_image( absint($datas['ts_color_image']), 'ts_prod_color_thumb', true, array('title'=>$term->name, 'alt'=>$term->name) ) . '</a>';
      }
      else{
        echo '<a href="#" style="background-color:' . $datas['ts_color_color'] . '">' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . '</a>';
      }
    }
    else{
      // !!!!!!!!!!MAIN ISSUE HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!
      if($term->count > 0){
        echo '<a href="#">' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . '</a>';
      }
    }

    echo '</div>';
  }
} else {

  foreach ( $options as $option ) {
    $class = sanitize_title( $selected_value ) == sanitize_title( $option ) ? 'selected' : '';
    $class .= ' option';
    echo '<div data-value="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '" class="' . $class . '"><a href="#">' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) ) . '</a></div>';
  }

}
```

Any idea how I could fix this? I have been at it for hours and I cannot find a solution for it. It's really frustrating.